# non captcha token timestamp in cookie vs session

Tags: session, captcha, token

The last days I have been reading some articles about NON Captcha's and more in particular on techniques on how to distinguish robots from humans.

- [Stackoverflow - Alternative to Annoying Captcha in Forms: How to SMELL the difference between a Human Customer and a Spammy Robot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4683117/alternative-to-annoying-captcha-in-forms-how-to-smell-the-difference-between-a-h)
- [SmashingMagazine - In Search Of The Perfect CAPTCHA](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/03/04/in-search-of-the-perfect-captcha/)
- [Sitepoint - Beyond CAPTCHA: No Bots Allowed!](http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/captcha-problems-alternatives)

At the end I went for a [jquery/PHP approach](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Safer_Contact_Forms_Without_CAPTCHAs) which goes like this:

**index.php**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $.get("captcha-token.php", function(txt) {
        $("#email-form").append('<input type="hidden" id="input-ts" name="ts" value="' + txt + '" />');
    });

    $("a.send-email-form").live('click', function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: _site_root + "ajax-email.php",
            type: "POST", 
            dataType: "json", 
            data: {
                from:   $("#input-from").val(), 
                to:     $("#input-to").val(), 
                body:   $("#input-body").val(),
                ts: $("#input-ts").val()
            },
            success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
                if (data.status) {
                    msg.text("Send!").addClass("email-msg-success");                    
                } else {
                    msg.text(data.msg).addClass("email-msg-error"); 
                    // show error fields
                    for (x in data.errorFields) {
                        $("#input-" + data.errorFields[x]).addClass("error");
                    }
                }
            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                msg.text("Error!" + " (" + textStatus + ")").addClass("email-msg-error");
            },
            complete: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus) {}
        });

        return false;
    });
});
```

**captcha-token.php**

```
$ct = mktime();
setcookie('token', md5('secret salt' . $ct), 0, '/');
echo $ct;
```

**ajax-email.php**

```
$proceed = false;
$seconds = 60 * 10;

if ( isset($_POST['ts']) && isset($_COOKIE['token']) && $_COOKIE['token'] == md5('secret salt' . $_POST['ts']) ) $proceed = true;

if (!$proceed) {
    echo '{"status":false, "msg":"! ' . _("Error. Form processing halted for suspicious activity.") . '"}';
    exit;
}

if ( ((int)$_POST['ts'] + $seconds) < mktime() ) {
    echo '{"status":false, "msg":"! ' . _("Error. Too much time elapsed. Please try again.") . '"}';
    exit;
}

mail($_POST['to'], $_POST['body'], "From: $from");
```

Now I was wondering….. why a cookie? Why not use PHP's $_SESSION?
Is there any reason for using a cookie vs session? I believe $_SESSION is more secure as it is more difficult to manipulate right?